# FatalErrorException in Model.php line 750: Class not found Laravel5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm currently in the process of upgrading a Laravel 4.2 project to 5.0 I've been making reasonable progress until this particular error:

**FatalErrorException in Model.php line 750: Class 'SAPProduct' not found.**

My SapProduct class is called from my Product class with a hasOne relationship and I can't work out why Laravel can't find it.

SapProduct.php

```
namespace App\Models;

use Eloquent;

class SapProduct extends Eloquent
{
    public function brand()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Brand', 'U_Brand', 'Name');
    }
}
```

Product.php

```
namespace App\Models;

use Eloquent;

class Product extends Eloquent
{
    ...
    public function sapProduct()
    {
        $relationship = $this->hasOne('App\Models\SapProduct', 'ItemCode', 'itemcode');
    }
    ...
}
```

Model.php (lines 746-755)

```
public function hasOne($related, $foreignKey = null, $localKey = null)
{
    $foreignKey = $foreignKey ?: $this->getForeignKey();

    $instance = new $related;

    $localKey = $localKey ?: $this->getKeyName();

    return new HasOne($instance->newQuery(), $this, $instance->getTable().'.'.$foreignKey, $localKey);
}
```

I apologise if I'm missing any other necessary information, I'll add more as/if requested.

Thanks

Comment: I do not know laravel but have you included the php file the classdefinition is? or does laravel that for you? in standart php you need a `require_once` of the file the class is definded.

Comment: Is the namespace ok for model SapProduct?

Comment: @KA_lin I would guess that this is a name spacing issue but I can't work out what the issue actually is. the SapProduct Model resides in the same location as all of the other models and is name spaced exactly the same but this is the model that is related with a hasOne relationship.

Comment: @inetphantom Laravel takes care of this for you.

Comment: Are your models resides in a directory named `Models`. Laravel uses PSR-4 standard to autoload classes. So make sure that all your classes which has a namespace `App\Models` resides within a directory named `Models` in your app directory.

Comment: @chanafdo Thanks but they already do.

Comment: I would check why is laravel reading your class as `SAPProduct` and not as `SapProduct`

Answer (score 1):

After spending far too much time on this problem I tracked it down to the offending line.

The relationship had chained through another model which had not had it's relationship to 'SapProduct' correctly namespaced.

The offending Model was ProductVariation.php and has the following incorrect line:

```
$relationship = $this->hasOne('SAPProduct', 'ItemCode', 'itemcode');
```

When it needed to be:

```
$relationship = $this->hasOne('App\Models\SAPProduct', 'ItemCode', 'itemcode');
```

This was also why laravel was bring the SapProduct error back in capitals rather than camel case.

Thanks to everybody who tried to help!

Comment: That helped me too! Thanks. Quite heavy the upgrade form 4.2 to 5.x Good luck. Keeping the use Eloquent instead of use /Illum../Eloquent/Model works?

Comment: @commandantp I'm glad it helped somebody other than me, yeah there is an awful lot to do with this upgrade and there are another 2 upgrades to go after this!
I'm having no issues with using 'use Eloquent' yet so I figure it's okay.

Comment: saved my another hours... @Joe1992

Answer (score 0):

If nothing seems to work and you have just stumbled upon this Question and you have just created the Model.

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

will do the magic, Along with giving the full path to the Model

```
 return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\YourModelClassName');
```

Source:: A wasted couple of hours going through the docs/posts and debugging.